# List tables with data on postgres

Tags: postgresql, dump

I've received a dump from a database, but since the database is huge, this is not a full dump.
There are hundreds of tables on there, but most of them are empty.
Is there a way to find what are the tables with data?

Comment: What format is the dump? A SQL script (aka "plain text" dump) or a custom format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a one option, you can use pgAdmin to create Statistic report (click on tables - Reports - Statistics report). It generates the html file with column consisting of number of rows in the table (live tuples).